# Getting object if count is less then a number

Tags: mysql, sql, sybase

I have 2 simple tables - `Firm` and `Groups`. I also have a table `FirmGroupsLink` for making connections between them (connection is one to many).

Table `Firm` has attributes           - `FirmID`, `FirmName`, `City`

Table `Groups` has attributes         - `GroupID`, `GroupName`

Table `FirmGroupsLink` has attributes - `FrmID`, `GrpID`

Now I want to make a query, which will return all those firms, that have less groups then @num, so I write

```
SELECT FirmID, FirmName, City
FROM (Firm INNER JOIN FirmGroupsLink ON Firm.FirmID =
FirmGroupsLink.FrmID) 
HAVING COUNT(FrmID)<@num
```

But it doesn't run, I try this in Microsoft Access, but it eventually should work for Sybase. Please show me, what I'm doing wrong. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to count properly, you need to provide by which group you are couting.
The having clause, and moreover the count can't work if you are not grouping.

Here you are counting by Firm. In fact, because you need to retrieve information about the Firm, you are grouping by FirmId, FirmName and City, so the query should look like this:

```
SELECT Firm.FirmID, Firm.FirmName, Firm.City
FROM Firm
    LEFT OUTER JOIN FirmGroupsLink 
        ON Firm.FirmID = FirmGroupsLink.FrmID
GROUP BY Firm.FirmID, Firm.FirmName, Firm.City
HAVING COUNT(FrmID) < @num
```

Note that I replace the `INNER JOIN` by a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, because you might want Firm which doesn't belongs to any groups too.

Comment: Great answer! That's exactly what I tried to do. Thanks for help!